# Why am I getting undefined instead of the selected value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, undefined

When a radio button is selected in this "form" I should be getting the value of the selected radio button, instead however I am getting undefined.  What is a possible reason for this and how can I fix it?  JSFIddle https://jsfiddle.net/uzuwheq4/

HTML

```
<div id="step2">
                    <span class="product" href="#" id="plan"><div class="plan" style="background-image:url(media/images/plan1.jpg);"><input class="radio" type="radio" value="plan1" name="plan"/></div><p>Enkel bankskiva</p></span>
                    <span class="product" href="#" id="plan"><div class="plan"  style="background-image:url(media/images/plan2.jpg);"><input class="radio" type="radio" value="plan2" name="plan"/></div><p>L-form</p></span>
                    <span class="product" href="#" id="plan"><div class="plan"  style="background-image:url(media/images/plan3.jpg);"><input class="radio" type="radio" value="plan3" name="plan"/></div><p>U-form</p></span>
                    <span class="product" href="#" id="plan"><div class="plan"  style="background-image:url(media/images/plan4.jpg);"><input class="radio" type="radio" value="plan4" name="plan"/></div><p>Mattbestallning</p></span>
                    <button type="button" class="nasta" onClick="processStep2()">Nasta</button>
                    <h3 id="alert2">Please select a plan to proceed</h3>
                </div>
```

JQuery

```
function _(x){
    return document.getElementById(x);
}

function processStep2(){
    plan = _('[name="plan"]').value;
    if ($(".radio").is(":checked")) {
     alert (plan);
        $("#phase2").removeClass("phase");
        $("#phase3").removeClass("main_list");
        $("#phase2").addClass("main_list");
        $("#phase3").addClass("phase");
    } else {
       $("#alert2").show();

    }

}
```

Comment: `plan = _("plan").value;`?? it should be `plan = $("#plan").val();`

Comment: 1. ID's are unique, 2. the `_` function is not needed, just use jQuery

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

`plan = $("#plan input[type='radio']:checked").val();`

Thinks you should take in mind.

- Don't use the same id for different elements.
- If you are using jQuery you dont need the function `_(x)` because `$("#elementID")` is the same of `document.getElementById(elementID);`

Comment: This works... try it with jsfiddle if you want https://jsfiddle.net/muc8an22/ before said something won't work first try it

Comment: hmmm, that's interesting it doesn't treat your selector like `$("#plan").find("input[type='radio']:checked").val()` which wouldn't work.

Comment: The difference is that if you use the selector `$("#plan")` and applies a function like `.find()` it will search within the first element with the selector, but if u use the selector `$("#plan input[type='radio']:checked")` first search an input type radio wich is selected within a element with the id plan.

Comment: ah yeah I keep forgetting jquery is rtl instead of ltr!

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are checking wrong element. Change

```
plan = _("plan").value;
```

to

```
var plan = $('[name="plan"]:checked').val();
```

Second thing is - id attribute should refer to only one DOM element =)

Answer (score 1):

There are several things I would change but I'll stick with the underlying question.  I changed the first line in your code to read:

```
    plan =$("input[name=plan]:checked").val();
```

this will only display "plan1" or "plan2", etc since that is the value defined on your radio button.  If you want to get the value within the p tag you would have to traverse the tree to get that value. I am assuming that this is what you truly want so I am updating my answer to include the code for this. First, a minor change in your html. I am moving the closing div to encapsulate the p tag, I am trying to preserve your original as much as possible.

```
    <div id="step2">  
       <span class="product" href="#" id="plan"><div class="plan"style="background-image:url(media/images/plan1.jpg);"><input class="radio" type="radio" value="plan1" name="plan"/><p>Enkel bankskiva</p></div></span>
       <span class="product" href="#" id="pl("plan").van"><div class="plan"  style="background-image:url(media/images/plan2.jpg);"><input lass="radio" type="radio" value="plan2" name="plan"/><p>L-form</p></div></span>                                 
       <span class="product" href="#" id="plan"><div class="plan"  style="background-image:url(media/images/plan3.jpg);"><input class="radio" type="radio" value="plan3" name="plan"/><p>U-form</p></div></span>
       <span class="product" href="#" d="plan"><div class="plan"  style="background-image:url(media/images/plan4.jpg);"><input class="radio" type="radio" value="plan4" name="plan"/><p>Mattbestallning</p></div></span>
       <button type="button" class="nasta" onClick="processStep2()">Nasta</button>
       <h3 id="alert2">Please select a plan to proceed</h3>
                </div>
```

then the first line of your processStep2 function should read:

```
    plan =$("input[name=plan]:checked").next("p").text();
```

this will spit out "Enkel bankskiva", "L-form", "U-form", "Mattbestallning"